# Collision Detection in Pygame and accordingly triggered action

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am aware there are multiple tutorials about collision detection in PyGame for Python out there, however I have not managed to solve my problem.
I have created a game board in Pygame where the fields on the board are in groups of sprites. The game figures are in their own sprite group.

My idea was that one rolls the dice (using `random.choice[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`) and based on the number on the dice, one can move the game figure across the game board and the code counts the number of fields that one passes so that one cannot trigger an action on a wrongly counted field.
When the figure landed on the designated field, I want to trigger customized actions based on the type of field.

For better illustration:
The game board consists of fields of different colors. Based on the color, a different action should be triggered.

My research as yielded that the most likely option to use seems to be `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(Player, Fields, False, False)` (i do not want to remove the player from its Sprite Group).
Unfortunately, the Python console only gives me an ouput about collisions when I close the game, not immediately upon collision. It neither gives me usable information about what kind of field it collided with. Another question at this point would be, should I create Sprite Group for every type of field or can I somehow access the type of field from within the group, like to know what color the field is.

The tutorials on the internet also hardly provide a full code where I can figure out how to insert the spritecollideany in my code.

I hope I have made myself understandable. Thanks a lot for your help!